# Profiling Result doesn't appear in event/metric summary mode nvprof

Tags: cuda, profiling, nvprof

According to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#event-summary-mode) for event/summary mode of `nvprof`, the output looks like:

```
==6461== Profiling application: matrixMul 
==6461== Profiling result: 
==6461== Event result: 
//The outputs 

==6461== Metric result: 
//The outputs
```

The [default](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#summary-mode) should show the latencies, percentages, etc for API calls and kernels under `Profiling result`. So there are two questions:

1. Why isn't any ouput under `Profiling Result`?
2. How do I get `nvprof` to output `Profiling Result` also?

Comment: Large program with many kernel calls?

Comment: @Eric: Yes. The answer was quite comprehensive though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't any ouput under Profiling Result?

According to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#profiling-modes), it states:

> `nvprof` operates in **one** of the modes listed below.

Those modes are:

- 3.1.1 Summary Mode (the default)
- 3.1.2 GPU-Trace and/or API-Trace Modes
- 3.1.3 Event/metric Summary Mode
- 3.1.4 Event/metric Trace Mode

Your excerpted info is from **3.1.3 Event/metric Summary Mode**.  When you are in this mode you are not in any of the other modes, and the data collection  (and output) description for the other modes does not apply.

> How do I get `nvprof` to output `Profiling Result` also?

If you want to capture metric info on a per-kernel basis, use 3.1.4 Event/metric Trace Mode.  Output will then appear in the `Profiling Result` section.

For other combinations, it's not possible to get `nvprof` to display an arbitrary collection of profiling data in a single run.  If you require output that is only available in a particular mode, you will need to run in that mode to get that output.  You may need to run `nvprof` multiple times to get all the output info or data that you'd like to collect.  `nvvp` (the visual profiler) does this (i.e. will run `nvprof` multiple times, under the hood) in order to display a greater range of data for a given application view.